# invoice order items file path in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

in magento invoice order items i want to show product price, qty and subtotal. I changed the order items in the below file path /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/invoice/items.php But no change. Anyone help me where and how to change the order items?

Answer (score 1):

These are the item HTML rendering templates for the following contexts (base theme):

**Invoice line items:**

- Email: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml`
- Web: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml`

**Order line items:**

- Email: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`
- Web: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`